# Upload Multiple Images with PHP and put it into MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Edit : solved! credits to @kaylined and @uli . i edited the code just in case someone in the future face the same problem with uploading multiple images at once and stored it into MYSQL Database.

i am trying to create upload multiple images at once script with PHP and MYSQL. but the script isn't working well. i don't know where i do wrong. maybe you guys could help. here is my code :

P.S : images are uploaded successfully, the file name is also stored to database successfully. but the "slug" variable is stored to database as "Array"

**Input Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="action-add-images.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="slug" value="<?php echo $_GET['slug']; ?>">
    <label>Upload Files</label>
    <input required type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control-file" multiple>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary my-3 ">Upload Images</button>
</form>
```

**Action File**

```
<?php
include "../connect.php";
    foreach ($_FILES['image']['name'] as $key => $name){
        $newFilename = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'.jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$key], '../img/' . $newFilename);
        $image = '../img/' . $newFilename;
        $slug = $_POST['slug'];
        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO product_image (slug,image) values ('$slug','$newFilename')");
    }
    header('location:product.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slug is saving as an array, because it is an array.

```
$slug = $_POST['slug'];
```

should solve your problem, assuming the slug elements are added in the same order as your files.

As per the comments, the above PHP has been fixed and the fixed HTML below - all I did was remove the array directive from the input:

```
<form method="POST" action="action-add-images.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="slug" value="<?php echo $_GET['slug']; ?>">
<label>Upload Files</label>
<input required type="file" name="image[]" class="form-control-file" multiple>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary my-3 ">Upload Images</button>
```

Comment: Slug is stored to database now, but when i uploaded 2 images, only 1 record that have a slug record. the other one is blank.

Comment: @RadenOctavian Should both images have the same slug? You only have a single input for slug in your HTML.

Comment: yes, both images should have the same slug. how do i multiply the slug input in my HTML? i have no idea how to do it. please help pal

Comment: @RadenOctavian fixed the answer for you.